# Getting the correct coordinates of all nodes to paint a tree

Tags: java, tree, swt

Hello stackoverflow community,

I have the following problem. Lets say I have a tree where each node has a variable amount of children (where leafs of course have 0 children and other nodes 1 to basically infinite children). I want to paint this tree using SWT. I don't want to know how to paint with SWT in general, but how to determine where to paint each node. What I would like most is the parent node to be centered over its children and to have enough space between siblings so their children don't collide with each other. My brain just won't come up with an algorithm to determine the positions. I hope somebody here can help.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers, Patrick

Comment: I don't know SWT but I bet it has a Tree component, so you have to provide tree data to the component and it will paint itself.

Comment: Well, SWT has a tree class, but it is that kind of tree you get when you are prompted to select a directory (where the directories are listed from top to bottom and when you click on one its children pop up, listed from top to bottom again). I don't know about an SWT component that can paint real graphical trees either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Breadth-first search. On each level, learn number of the nodes in the level, then do calculation and paint them, move to the next level on tree, so on.

Comment: I think I will run into problems using this. When painting a level with only 2 nodes and the level below them has suddenly 1000 nodes, these 2 nodes won't be centered over their children anymore.

Comment: first you will centralize the root, then you on the second level since there is two nodes, you will divide the screen into two parts and centralize the nodes in their sub-screens.@patrick-szostack

Answer (score 0):

I think of following steps to figure out the bounds to draw the tree.

1. You need to know number of leaf nodes (n) in the tree ( to center parent nodes properly)
2. You need to know depth (d) of the tree.
3. Specify parameters like vertical spacing (vs), horizontal spacing (hs) for each level of the tree.
4. Implement `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout` and calculate bounds of the nodes at each level

Answer (score -1):

Think of a file tree in any OS. its that exact scenario. Look at http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JTree.html to see how to implement one! Not really sure if you were looking for how to implement it or paint it yourself but I would not recommend painting it yourself.

Comment: First, the question is for SWT, not Swing. Second, OP is specifically asking for a Graph layout, not a file tree layout.